# selectize.js - how can reference some property of the select element during load()?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js:

- I have a number of similar select boxes
- Options are loaded dynamically from the server, during `load()`
- The query made during `.load()` is unique to each select box. Eg, I'd like to have a
  `.load()` hit a different URL based on some property of the select box (eg, `data-someproperty`).

How can I do that? Code right now is almost identical to the [**Remote Source** example from the Selectize docs](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/).

```
$('.select-repo').selectize({
    valueField: 'url',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    create: false,
    ...
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/' + encodeURIComponent(query),
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res.repositories.slice(0, 10));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried checking out `this` during .load() but I can't see any reference to the original element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it:

Inside load(), access:

```
this.$input
```

To get a JQuery selection with the `<select>` element.

```
this.$input.data('whatever')
```

Would return `data-whatever` from the `select`